# Why is final output being printed on the terminal even though there is no print statement in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, output, pycharm

In the given code below:

```
with open("chr2_head25.gtf", 'r') as f,\
    open('test_output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for lines in f:
        if not lines.startswith('#'):
            f2.write(lines)
    f2.close()
```

I am able to strip the lines starting with `#` and write the output to a new file. But, the glitch is that the `f2 i.e the output` is getting printed on the console even though there is no print statement anywhere on the code. **Why is this happening? I tried to find explanation but couldn't. The program works but I don't want the massive `data file (f2)` being printed on the screen.**

thanks,

**Input file:** Here is the data file named `chr2_head25.gtf`

```
#!genome-build v.1.0
#!genome-version JGI8X
#!genome-date 2008-12
#!genome-build-accession GCA_000004255.1
#!genebuild-last-updated 2008-12
2   jgi gene    171 1201    .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi transcript  171 1201    .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi exon    916 1201    .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "scaffold_200001.1.exon1"; exon_version "1";
2   jgi CDS 916 1181    .   -   0   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "scaffold_200001.1"; protein_version "1";
2   jgi start_codon 1179    1181    .   -   0   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi exon    614 789 .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "2"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "scaffold_200001.1.exon2"; exon_version "1";
2   jgi CDS 614 789 .   -   1   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "2"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "scaffold_200001.1"; protein_version "1";
2   jgi exon    171 435 .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "3"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "scaffold_200001.1.exon3"; exon_version "1";
2   jgi CDS 194 435 .   -   2   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "3"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "scaffold_200001.1"; protein_version "1";
2   jgi stop_codon  191 193 .   -   0   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "3"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi five_prime_utr  1182    1201    .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi three_prime_utr 171 190 .   -   .   gene_id "scaffold_200001.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200001.1"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi gene    1343    3488    .   +   .   gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"; gene_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi transcript  1343    3488    .   +   .   gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200002.1"; transcript_version "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
2   jgi exon    1343    1612    .   +   .   gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200002.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; exon_id "scaffold_200002.1.exon1"; exon_version "1";
2   jgi CDS 1364    1612    .   +   0   gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200002.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding"; protein_id "scaffold_200002.1"; protein_version "1";
2   jgi start_codon 1364    1366    .   +   0   gene_id "scaffold_200002.1"; gene_version "1"; transcript_id "scaffold_200002.1"; transcript_version "1"; exon_number "1"; gene_source "jgi"; gene_biotype "protein_coding"; transcript_source "jgi"; transcript_biotype "protein_coding";
```

If I do:

```
print(f)
print(f2)
# I get

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='chr2_head25.gtf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test_output.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

But, without any `print` statement anywhere on the code I get the f2 data (i.e the final output) printed on the terminal. Why?

Comment: Are you in interactive mode?

Comment: I don't think so. I wrote the code on pycharm which game me this issue. But, then i ran the python file using `python code.py`, but still having the same problem.

Comment: Clsoing `f2` is redundant in the code. I know that. But, my problem is different which closing f2 has nothing to do.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause that behavior.  Is that all of the code you're running?

Comment: Yes, starting from `with open(....) ... to f2.close()`. Nothing else in the code. The problem is seen in both `pycharm output` as well as `terminal`.

Comment: Can someone please try this code and input in their computer and see if you are seeing the same problem??

Comment: Are you sure "the console" you're looking at isn't actually connected to `test_output.txt` instead of or in addition to your program's standard output?

Comment: **I am not sure. Is there any way to test that?** `f2` is written to file as `test_output.txt`, so are basically the same thing. But, the problem is why is this getting printed to terminal without any `print` statement inside the code. Did you had time to check that in your computer `(using the code and input I provided)`.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem using the provided code and input.

Comment: Hmm, In that case I assume there is internal problem in my computer. So, I don't need to worry about the code at all. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many others who commented here I have run your code in Python2.7 and Python3.5 without being able to reproduce the behavior you have described.

So the right answer to your question is what you stated already yourself:

"""Hmm, In that case I assume there is internal problem in my computer. So, I

> **don't need to worry about the code**

at all"""

Comment: This is the best answer ever ! :)

Comment: @everestial007 :D , so what about upvoting it? :D

Comment: Well, you got it .